# Flask-Socketio and stopping infinite while true loops in background task threads, with an event

Tags: javascript, python, multithreading, flask-socketio, background-task

I have a program that starts an infinite background task in a thread upon an event with socketio.on('event') initiated by javascript. However, if I try to repeat this task again the originally event continues looping and does not break/stop to start and recognize that a new task has been initiated. What can I place in my socketio.on('event') handle to stop this original thread, wait for it to terminate, and start a new background task everytime someone searches for something?

I tried doing something like this in my event handling function but it wont stop and restart. I feel I might be close.

Python Code:

```
@socketio.on('contract_type')
def handleContract(ticker, expiration, strike, side):
    #adding searched contract to contracts_searched database
    print('Started Search for Contract Event!')
    contract = ContractsSearched(ticker=ticker, expiration=expiration, strike=strike, side=side)
    db.session.add(contract)
    db.session.commit()

    global stop_threads
    stop_threads = True
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Thread Stopped!')
    stop_threads = False
    print('Thread Started Again')
    global thread
    print('All threads killed and waited for termination!')
    print('Initiated a new search with a new thread!')
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = socketio.start_background_task(datafeed(ticker=ticker, expiration=expiration, strike=strike, side=side))
        emit('options_data', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0})
```

Background task function:

```
def datafeed(ticker='SPY', expiration='2022-04-14', strike='442', side='call'):
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        try:
            option_historicals = historical_options_data(ticker=ticker, expiration=expiration, strike=strike, side=side)
            option_historicals = option_historicals.to_json(orient='records')
            live_options = live_options_data(ticker, expiration, strike, side)
            live_options_bid = str(round(float(live_options[0][0]), 2))
            live_options_bid_size = str(int(live_options[0][1]))
            live_options_ask = str(round(float(live_options[0][2]),2))
            live_options_ask_size = str(int(live_options[0][3]))
        except:
            print('Error getting data in background thread')
            continue
        socketio.emit('options_data', {'bid_price': live_options_bid, 'bid_size': live_options_bid_size, 
        'ask_size': live_options_ask_size, 'ask_price': live_options_ask,'count': count})
        socketio.emit('options_historicals', {'historicals': option_historicals})
        #socketio.emit('stock_data', {'stock_historicals': stock_historicals, 'live_stock_data': stock_data})
        global stop_threads
        if stop_threads == True:
            break
```

I have read about the .join() method but I cant figure out a way to incorporate it with the global thread declaration because I did not initialize that as a thread.Thread(). Whenever, I run this current program, as mentioned above, the front-end javascript, that signals an event upon a search does not console.log() the new contract that was searched, but instead just keeps the first event loop going regardless of how many new events I initiate. I did not provide javascript as I do not know how valuable it is as I believe it to be a server side issue. I can provide if needed though. Thank you!

Comment: The "Python Events" section in this [blog post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-kill-a-python-thread) has the proper way to kill a thread.

Comment: Thank you Miguel. I had seen the blog post prior to asking this question, but could not get a working program. I now just did find a solution. I have read a bunch of your posts and watched a bunch of your youtube videos. Thank you for your committment to solving complex issues!